# Inserting tracker inside input range

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I insert an tracker inside input range? Here is my code =>

```js
const marker = document.createElement('div');
marker.classList.add('range-marker');

const range = document.getElementById('range');
range.appendChild(marker);

range.addEventListener('input', () => {
    const percent = (range.value - range.min) / (range.max - range.min);
    const pixels = percent * range.offsetWidth;
    marker.style.left = `${pixels}px`;
});
```

```css
.range-marker {
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="range">
```

I don't know how but isn't working. There are no errors... can you please help me fixing it?

Thank you.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do. What is the definition of a "tracker", and why have you appended a div into an input element?

Comment: I just want to insert a red dot inside my input, to replicate an video tracker, like youtube. Something like this => https://prnt.sc/0Qi_bDT5kuXp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You bascially need to put the input and the range marker inside a wrapper and use absolute position on range marker to position the red tracker. This can be implemented like below. Please note the appending div will go inside the wrapper and not the input.

```js
const marker = document.createElement('div');
marker.classList.add('range-marker');
const range = document.getElementById('container');
range.appendChild(marker);
range.addEventListener('input', () => {
    const percent = (range.value - range.min) / (range.max - range.min);
    const pixels = percent * range.offsetWidth;
    marker.style.left = `${pixels}px`;
});
```

```css
.range-marker {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left:60%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 100;
}
#container{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<input type="range" id="range">
</div>
```